# Issue returning a string from WebMethod in sitecore

Tags: jquery, ajax, sitecore, webmethod

I have the following ajax method within my sitecore project

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/layouts/WebMethods.aspx/SaveSubscription',
        data: { hello: 'TestData' },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);

            $('#newsletter-signup section.form').fadeOut(0);
            $('#newsletter-signup section.thankyou').fadeIn();
        },
        error: function (request, error) {


            alert(error);

            alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
```

When my submit button is pressed it fires the above which in turn calls the following webmethod:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string SaveSubscription(string hello)
    {

       return "hello";
    }
```

however when the call comes back and logs data into the console I see the following:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head><title>
</title></head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="/layouts/WebMethods.aspx/SaveSubscription" id="form1">

<div class="aspNetHidden">

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjkPFgIeE1ZhbGlkYXRlUmVxdWVzdE1vZGUCAWRkhKZL+kK5CfzPtpuWvMk8nCH9ZzR7QgL8q7X8hM86IDw=" />

</div>
<div>
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="4D781013" />

</div></form>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->

<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">

{"appName":"Firefox","requestId":"6592f28a894c4e99864e5a04ca41358a"}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:56165/0b7f5b34dc2e4e69a24b14da69a7adb9/browserLink" async="async"></script>

<!-- End Browser Link -->
</body>

</html>
```

realistically I would expect to see the word "hello", however I get the above.

Unfortunately I'm unable to debug this call, due to it being a sitecore project, and also the PC I have is very very slow / borderline crap, and trying to attach a process within Visual Studio takes me roughly 45 minutes for the project to start, and even then its hit and miss.

Now I'm not sure if anyone can help me but I thought I'll give it a shot.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I have changed my ajax method to now look like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/layouts/WebMethods.aspx/SaveSubscription',
        data: { hello: 'testData'},
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json", // New
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // New
        success: function (data) {
            alert('In Success');

            alert(data);

            $('#newsletter-signup section.form').fadeOut(0);
            $('#newsletter-signup section.thankyou').fadeIn();
        },
        error: function (request, error) {


            alert(error);

            alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
```

It now hits the error method and alerts:

```
Request: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"Message\":\"Invalid JSON primitive: subscribe.\",\"StackTrace\":\"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\\r\\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\\r\\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\\r\\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\\r\\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\\r\\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)\",\"ExceptionType\":\"System.ArgumentException\"}","responseJSON":{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: subscribe.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"},"status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you need to have access to Sitecore.Context or not, there's two options that comes in mind

- Webservice (no access to Sitecore.Context)

  - Create a new folder under /website, and name it WebServices
  - In the IgnoreUrlPrefixes setting add the "/Webservices" path
  - Create new webservice class and test your ajax script again
- Sitecore item web api (access to Sitecore.Context)

  - A good example if provided here http://sitecorejunkie.com/category/sitecore-item-web-api/

Comment: I'm very new to Sitecore so the steps you mentioned I'll have to follow one of them just to get a simple ajax request working?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/layouts/WebMethods.aspx/SaveSubscription',
    data: { hello: 'TestData' },
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.d);

        $('#newsletter-signup section.form').fadeOut(0);
        $('#newsletter-signup section.thankyou').fadeIn();
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);

    }
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.